# Android Studio Error Running 'app'; The application could not be installed

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, failed-installation

I recently updated to Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1, Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570. I am on a MacOS (Sonoma 14.4 on my personal computer, Ventura 13.6.3 on work computer)

I updated yesterday on my personal computer first so as to not disrupt work flow. Got everything up and running on that. Our app was building and installing on the phone when debugging. I then updated my work computer and experienced the same.

This morning, neither will install to any of my Android devices. I get the error "Error Running 'app'; The application could not be installed".

[image]

I have tried resetting both computers, invalidated caches on Android Studio, restarted the Android devices and even went to factory reset. Nothing has worked.

Is there anywhere to start looking for details on why it won't install?

Comment: Same happening with me.

Answer (score 18):

After a coworker and I were playing with the settings in Android Studio, we were able to get our app to install to physical devices.

We went to Edit Configurations -> Android App
under Installation Options, we changed Deploy to APK from app bundle

[image]

Comment: awesome, this is not mentioned in any of docs.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, took me an hour before stumbling to this thread. Frustrating that it doesn't include any informative error messages. Good job once again to the Google Android Team.

Comment: Thanks. App was installing OK on devices with Android 10+, but failed to install on Android 9 phone. Changing this setting helped.

Answer (score 1):

My friend was having same issue and spent hours without getting the issue fixed. We got it solved by changing configuration.

> New project created in Android Studio Iguana works fine.

### Step 1 :

[image]

### Step 2 :

[image]

Now when you run the app, It'll get installed.